# whats the difference between "Dell" Ubuntu and ubuntu from website?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, software-recommendation, dell

I bought Dell laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 on it, with some software "Dell Recovery", "Dell Linux Assistance"(maybe something cut). I am thinking of installing OS from https://ubuntu.com/
What can you suggest?

Comment: The basic Ubuntu OS should work just as well, but think the extra Dell software is to help you instead of the bloatware you would find on Windows computers.  I doubt any difference between Ubuntu OS and Dell Ubuntu, except Dell would have provided all drivers needed for best use.  Can use the Ubuntu live USB to check.

Comment: @crip659 i was thinking about some stealers, maybe tracking software, miners

Comment: With Ubuntu/Linux being open source, do not think that Dell could get away with that stuff.  People better than us would find it.  Most of that stuff can be placed in your browser from bad ads on sites, anti-tracking and ad blocker extensions are almost required for browsers.  If you decide to change, would use the live USB option to make sure all hardware works first, some drivers might need to be added.

Comment: @crip659 Yeah, you are right, it is open source so there is no reason to be afraid of that

Comment: Open source just means people can check, does not mean they will.   Hopefully they do not trust Dell.  Has been a number of years that Dell supplied Ubuntu, so someone might have.